# prevent page refresh by submit a post action from a normal clickevent

Tags: jquery, events, click, submit

Can I prevent a page refresh from this code?

As you can see, I submit a post action from a normal click_event, which I need
because live does not support submit events.

```
jQuery('.verwijder').live('click', function() { 
    t=$(this);

    t.parents(".paneltbnote").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow",function(){
        t.parents(".wrappertbnote").remove();
        settbnotecounter();

        $db_tbnoteid = t.parents(1).children('.frmnoteid').val();

        $.post("tbnotesact.php", {
            noteid: $db_tbnoteid,
            actie: "verwijder",
            tijd: timestamp
        }, function(xml) {
            // hier nog iets doen
            berichtentoevoegen(xml);//feedback
        });//einde post methode

    });// einde callback animate methode

    return false;    
});//einde binding click event
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

replace the first line with

```
jQuery('.verwijder').live('click', function(e) { t=$(this);
```

and replace
    return false;
with

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work
The click event is not attached to a link if you thought so

Comment: I think the post method within the function is causing this

Answer (score 2):

You are returning false in the click event but it's not going to stop the submit action, unfortunately. If you have the option of *not* using the live event listener, you can always just watch the submit action with the bind() method.

```
jQuery('.verwijder').bind('submit', function() {
    /* everything as usual... */
    return false;
});
```

Of course, if that's not an option, you might just have to add some logic into your code that will unbind and then rebind all forms' submit actions to do what you want.

```
$(function() {
    bind_submits();
    // Let's pretend you have a link that adds forms to your page...
    $('#addForm').live('click', function() {
        add_form();
    });
});

function bind_submits() {
   // We need to unbind first to make we don't multi-bind 
   jQuery('.verwijder').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        /* everything as usual... */
        return false;
    });
}

function add_form() {
    /* do some stuff to add a form to your layout... */

    // Now reset all current 'submit' binds and add the new one...
    bind_submits();
}
```

This is what had to be done for all event listeners before the live() method was added (if you didn't use the livequery plugin of course). It's more coding and harder to maintain but there aren't really too many other options at the moment that I'm aware of.

Happy jQuerying...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, if theres an error in the code, javascript never gets to complete the function up to "return false;" resulting in a page reload. Take off the link for now, and see if any errors pop-up.

Comment: I am  embarrased, it was something in the code that caused it
I did not see it. After not looking at it for an houer it hit me.