# ajax post but can't prevent refresh

Tags: php, ajax, post, page-refresh

I have a problem with my page refreshing after ajax posts, I've tried like 6 differing variations and at one point I was getting the proper result but couldn't stop the page from refreshing and after searching the net and around on this site now none of it is working and it's still refreshing...

current code is:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
/*event.preventDefault();*/
var curPassword = $("input#curPassword").val();
var newPassword = $("input#newPassword").val();
var new2Password = $("input#new2Password").val();
/*var params = 'curPassword='+ curPassword + '&newPassword=' + newPassword + '&new2Password=' + new2Password; */
var params = {
    curPassword: curPassword,
    newPassword: newPassword,
    new2Password:new2Password
};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testAjax.php",
        data: params,
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

the form is:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="confirmChange" class="confirmChange">
<label for="curPassword">Current Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="curPassword" id="curPassword" value="" />
<label for="newPassword">New Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" value="" />
<label for="new2Password">Confirm New Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="new2Password" id="new2Password" value="" />
<br />
<input type="button" name="confirmChange" class="confirmChange" id="submit_btn" value="Change" />
```

Appreciate any help in getting this to work =/

**Update:**
Took out the other non-directly-related code as it kinda cluttered the question.  Also updated code to refelect latest revision.
I changed the ajax url to a simple textAjax.php with a simple echo hello world nothing else, where I'm still getting nothing.

**Update 2**
Tried changing javascript code to:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

And I'm getting nothing... If that is the form below how is it possible the click function isn't working at all?

Comment: I think you might need to look into preventDefault(). I'm not sure how jQuery works, but I think you have to call this function instead of returning false.

Comment: close your button :) /> may add some progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it by using:

```
$('#submit_btn').live('click', (function() {
```

I at least started getting a response when clicking, but I'm not updating or getting any echo's back from the php file but hopefully that'll be easier to debug. :)

Comment: Yup, working perfectly now! really owe a big things to: http://stackoverflow.com/users/634752/sbeliv01 from another post. I can't send private messages either because I'm to new to the site or this site just doesn't have them or I'd love to thank him as he's actually solved a lot of my problems inadvertantly. :)  I always thought it was used like: $('#submit_btn').live().click(function() { which never worked... and left in situations like this question had.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the type="submit" for your input.  Just use type="button" and call the ajax function on the button's click event.

```
<input type="button" name="confirmChange" class="confirmChange" id="submit_btn" value="Change">

$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
  (ajax code here)
});
```

preventDefault() would also work, but, in my opinion, why prevent an event from naturally occurring when you can just avoid using the submit button altogether?

**Update:**  I just realised that using the submit would allow users to hit enter to trigger your actions, so perhaps there's also some merit in that.  In any case, [here's a similar question that contains elaborations into preventDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887712/prevent-page-refresh-by-submit-a-post-action-from-a-normal-clickevent).

**Update 2:**  You need to fix your parameters in the ajax function.  Use an array instead of trying to build a query string:

```
var params = {
curPassword: curPassword,
newPassword: newPassword,
new2Password:new2Password
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited the original post with the updated code, and it's not refreshing but it doesn't seem to be posting as I'm not getting any change in the db, nor any feedback from the php page...

Comment: See my update in the answer above.  Your parameters aren't being passed properly.

Comment: have you tried posting it normally and seeing what changePassword.php returns?

Comment: yeah, worked for a while, even through the ajax but wouldn't not refresh no matter what I tried... only thing i've touched since is the ajax post code and the little form changes suggested here.  Sadly now it's not refreshing but it's also not submitting

Comment: Take out preventDefault().  That function prevents the default action  from being triggered.  In this case, it's possible it's interfering with the click() event.

Comment: I tested your code and can confirm that it reaches the success: function.  You might want to check your changePassword.php file and make sure you're actually echoing some text and not simply returning it.  Otherwise, I'm stumped.
P.S. your form class has an extra double-quote.

Comment: Haha, i noticed the quote too, thanks! hmmm, how do you have the script print out any echo's from the php file?  I've got it echoing something every step of the way...

Comment: threw alert('success'); in the success function and not getting anything :(

Comment: Here's your code.  The only thing I changed which you don't have is that I added success(msg) in order to capture from the success.php script that the form posts to. http://www.jesusismetal.com/form.php

Comment: very strange, copied the script and form from source, changed the url:  not reaching success()... I'm so lost

Comment: if you had 20 rep, we could chat :(  Is the path in the AJAX url parameter correct?  Is it relative to the form script's location?  Also, in this case, have a look at your javascript console, there might be an error being thrown somewhere else in your code that's killing that script.

Comment: path is right its in the same folder--no error/s---worked when it was refreshing the page, but that was 50+revisions ago

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I had to try and get some sleep, and won't be able to be around much for the next few hours, hopefully tonight I'll be able to get this solved.  It's painful for something so simple to cost so much in time.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your AJAX call within the following code block

```
$('form.confirmChange').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      #Rest of your code goes in here
});
```

preventDefault() will prevent the default action of an event from triggering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
function refreshpage(){
 (ajax code here)
  return false;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return refreshpage();">
<input type = "submit" value="submit_btn">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just like you, I had wrapped my `<input>` tags inside a `<form>` tag pair. Even though there was no `<submit>`, I found that when I clicked my button to trigger the Ajax call, it was refreshing the page - and actually submitting the form to the page.

I ended up removing the `<form>` tags and this behaviour stopped, but the Ajax still works as expected. I hope this helps anyone else that is experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to run the ajax call only once.

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<1;i++){
//ajax code here
}
```

So, then it will not call again and again..

Comment: If you'll define `var i;` in same stack - it will be called every time, as every time `i` will not be initialized.